# can I restore lost source code from it's cmake files?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have accidentally backed up the wrong version of my source code for an application I developed months ago. However I was able to recover all the Cmake files and the binaries. Is it at all possible to get my source code back from the file.cc.o files that Cmake generated ? knowing that many libraries and headers where used as well.

I have tried opening the file.cc.o files in editors without luck. I'm not very experienced in the field so I really don't know if its possible. but I sure think so, since I have the pre-compilation files.

here is the cmakelists.txt that I used to generate everything

```
# $Id: CMakeLists.txt 86065 2014-11-07 08:51:15Z gcosmo $

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Setup the project
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6 FATAL_ERROR)
project(box)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Find Geant4 package, activating all available UI and Vis drivers by default
# to build a batch mode only executable
#
option(WITH_GEANT4_UIVIS "Build a box with Geant4 UI and Vis drivers" ON)
if(WITH_GEANT4_UIVIS)
  find_package(Geant4 REQUIRED ui_all vis_all)
else()
  find_package(Geant4 REQUIRED)
endif()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Setup Geant4 include directories and compile definitions
# Setup include directory for this project
#
include(${Geant4_USE_FILE})
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)


#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Locate sources and headers for this project
# NB: headers are included so they will show up in IDEs
#
file(GLOB sources ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cc)
file(GLOB headers ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/*.hh)


# Add the executable, and link it to the Geant4 libraries
#
add_executable(Neutron_Detector neutron_detector.cc ${sources} ${headers})
target_link_libraries(Neutron_Detector ${Geant4_LIBRARIES})


# Install the executable to 'bin' directory under CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX
#
install(TARGETS Neutron_Detector DESTINATION bin)
```

Comment: Arent't the .cc.o files object files? If so, you're mostly out of luck. There are some decompilers, but if you compiled with optimizations enabled then it's gonna be pretty far off from what you had.

Comment: @IGarFieldI even with a decompiler on unoptimized code the result will be almost worthless. At this point I'd say the code is lost forever unless there are other backups.

Comment: It is probably a good time to stat using some distributed Version Control System, such as [Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/).

Comment: That's how you learn about the necessity of Git.

Comment: Notes taken... already started working on replacement code for the lost project since decompiler output was rubbish. Beginner mistake I'm afraid. Thanks